# How to create semi-auto open collapsible in CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have collapsibles inside collapsibles, and I'd like for all the levels beneath the first one to open up whenever the first level is click on.

So for example, if I click on Act 1, I'd like everything under Scene 1 and 2, including all the Snippets, to open up whenever Act 1 is clicked.

Here is my attempt at the basic coding, which functions in itself. I just need to figure out how to incorporate the added level of difficulty.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #0486C1;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #254062;
}

.collapsible::after {
  content: '\002B';
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

p {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Act 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 1</button>
  <div class="content">
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 2</button>
  <div class="content">
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```js
const collapsibles = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");
collapsibles.forEach(collapsible => {
  collapsible.addEventListener("click", function() {
    open(this);
    const children = this.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
    children.forEach(open);
  });
});

function open(element) {
  element.classList.toggle("active");
  var content = element.nextElementSibling;
  if (content.style.display === "block") {
    content.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #0486C1;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #254062;
}

.collapsible::after {
  content: '\002B';
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

p {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Act 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 1</button>
  <div class="content">
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 2</button>
  <div class="content">
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggested approach would be the following:

```js
// I've chosen to use 'let' to declare variables, since they're more easily
// scoped than variables declared with 'var';
// here we retrieve the elements with the class-name of 'collapsible'
// using the CSS selector passed to the document.querySelectorAll() method:
let collapsibles = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible'),

  // declaring the toggleContent function using Arrow syntax, since we
  // don't need to use the 'this' argument within the function body;
  // we pass in the Event Object (supplied automatically by the
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() call later):
  toggleContent = (evt) => {
    // here we retrieve the element that was clicked, and which triggered
    // the event-listener:
    let clicked = evt.target,
        
        // we retrieve the next-element sibling:
        content = clicked.nextElementSibling,

        // and find the appropriate display-type for
        // for that neighbouring element; here we use
        // a conditional ('ternary') operator to determine
        // what the approapriate display-type should be
        // based on its current display:
        displayType = content.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';

    // updating the display of the content:
    content.style.display = displayType;
    
    // finding all '.content' elements within the content
    // element-node using Element.querySelectorAll(), and then
    // iterating over those elements using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
    content.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(
      // here the first argument of the anonymous Arrow function
      // refers to the current '.content' element-node of
      // the NodeList over which we're iterating; this is passed
      // to the function-body, in which we update its display
      // to be the same as the 'outer' content:
      (currentContent) => currentContent.style.display = displayType
    );
  };

// here we iterate over the NodeList of '.collapsible' elements using
// NodeList.prototype.forEach() along with an anonymous Arrow function:
collapsibles.forEach(
  // 'collapseButton' refers to the current element of the NodeList
  // of element-nodes; within the function body this is used to
  // bind the toggleContent() function (note the deliberate lack of
  // parentheses) to the 'click' event of the '.collapsible' element:
  (collapseButton) => collapseButton.addEventListener('click', toggleContent)
);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: #0486C1;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #254062;
}

.collapsible::after {
  content: '\002B';
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

p {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Act 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 1</button>
  <div class="content">
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 2</button>
  <div class="content">
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xsr6f5by/).

References:

- [Arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Conditional ("ternary") operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling).
- [`ElementCSSInlineStyle.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
- [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).